# Mongoose: findByIdAndUpdate() How To Conditionally Update Based On Existing Data?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

When using `findByIdAndUpdate()` or `findOneAndUpdate()` (that is, updating the database atomically to avoid race conditions), is there a way to reference the existing data to conditionally update a field?

```js
PersonModel.findByIdAndUpdate(
  req.user.id, 
  {
    $set: { 
      // set this to true 
      // if person.color === blue for example
      hasFavoriteColor: true, 
    }
  },
  { new: true },
  (err, updatedDoc => {
    if (err) return;
    return updatedDoc;
  });
);
```

Comment: Can you explain with some examples?

Comment: @TusharGupta-curioustushar Looking to update a requireEmailVerification field if the user saves over their existing email. So essentially the requireEmailVerification field would be set to true if `oldEmail !== newEmail`. oldEmail would be already saved in the document, newEmail is a variable used to compare to oldEmail

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can do that, I see nowhere in the document. However, for your query particularly, you can add the condition about the color in the filter part, something like this :

```
PersonModel.findOneAndUpdate(
  {_id : req.user.id, color : "blue"},
  {
    $set: { 
      // set this to true 
      // if person.color === blue for example
      hasFavoriteColor: true, 
    }
  },
  { new: true },
  (err, updatedDoc => {
    if (err) return;
    return updatedDoc;
  });
);
```